# Web scraping with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I'd like to grab daily sunrise/sunset times from a web site. Is it possible to scrape web content with Python? what are the modules used? Is there any tutorial available?

Comment: Python has several options for web scraping.
I enumerated some of the options [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping/1970411#1970411) in response to a similar question.

Comment: Why not just use the built in HTML Parser in the Python Standard Library? Certainly for a task so simple and infrequent (just once a day), I see little reason to search for any other tools. https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/htmlparser.html

Comment: Hope this post might be useful to somebody regarding this. A good tutorial for a beginner. http://samranga.blogspot.com/2015/08/web-scraping-beginner-python.html It uses beautiful soup python library for web scraping with python.

Comment: For future readers, you may want to have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70962929/17865804) as well, which provides two different approaches as reagrds web scraping, using (1) [`Selenium`](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) and (2) [`BeautifulSoup`](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) with [`Requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/).

Comment: Here is a tutorial that can help: https://www.camelcodes.net/web-scraping-python-beautifulsoup-image-processing-html/

Answer (score 196, accepted):

Use urllib2 in combination with the brilliant [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) library:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
# or if you're using BeautifulSoup4:
# from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com').read())

for row in soup('table', {'class': 'spad'})[0].tbody('tr'):
    tds = row('td')
    print tds[0].string, tds[1].string
    # will print date and sunrise
```

Comment: Small comment: this can be slightly simplified using the requests package by replacing line 6 with: soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('http://example.com').text)

Comment: thanks for the tip. the request package did not yet exist, when I wrote the snippet above ;-)

Comment: @DerrickCoetzee - your simplification raises a MissingSchema error (at least on my installation). This works: `soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('http://example.com').text)`

Comment: @kmote: that was what I typed but I forgot the `backticks` around the code and it converted it into a link. Thanks!

Comment: How are you sure that the content will be in td and tr. It can be in ul and li also right?

Comment: Hope this post might be useful to somebody regarding this. A good descriptive tutorial for a beginner. http://samranga.blogspot.com/2015/08/web-scraping-beginner-python.html It uses beautiful soup python library for web scraping with python.

Comment: @DCoetzee: requests lib is slower than urllib or urllib2. This can be slowly if you scrape some sites.

Comment: Note that `urllib2` does not exist for `Python3`. [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792650/import-error-no-module-name-urllib2)

Answer (score 66):

I'd really recommend Scrapy.

Quote from a deleted answer:

> - Scrapy crawling is fastest than mechanize because uses asynchronous operations (on top of Twisted).
> - Scrapy has better and fastest support for parsing (x)html on top of libxml2.
> - Scrapy is a mature framework with full unicode, handles redirections, gzipped responses, odd encodings, integrated http cache, etc.
> - Once you are into Scrapy, you can write a spider in less than 5 minutes that download images, creates thumbnails and export the extracted data directly to csv or json.

Comment: I didn't notice this question was already 2 years old, still feel that Scrapy should be named here in case someone else is having the same question.

Comment: Scrapy is a framework, and therefore is horrible and thinks it's more important than your project. It's a framework because of the horrible (unnecessary) limitations of Twisted.

Comment: @user1244215: It's a framework because frameworks are nice. If you don't want to use it as a framework, there's nothing stopping you from jamming all of your code into one file.

Comment: But it does not support Python 3.x.

Answer (score 18):

I collected together scripts from my web scraping work into this [bit-bucket library](https://bitbucket.org/richardpenman/webscraping).

Example script for your case:

```
from webscraping import download, xpath
D = download.Download()

html = D.get('http://example.com')
for row in xpath.search(html, '//table[@class="spad"]/tbody/tr'):
    cols = xpath.search(row, '/td')
    print 'Sunrise: %s, Sunset: %s' % (cols[1], cols[2])
```

Output:

```
Sunrise: 08:39, Sunset: 16:08
Sunrise: 08:39, Sunset: 16:09
Sunrise: 08:39, Sunset: 16:10
Sunrise: 08:40, Sunset: 16:10
Sunrise: 08:40, Sunset: 16:11
Sunrise: 08:40, Sunset: 16:12
Sunrise: 08:40, Sunset: 16:13
```

Answer (score 11):

I would strongly suggest checking out [pyquery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery). It uses jquery-like (aka css-like) syntax which makes things really easy for those coming from that background.

For your case, it would be something like:

```
from pyquery import *

html = PyQuery(url='http://www.example.com/')
trs = html('table.spad tbody tr')

for tr in trs:
  tds = tr.getchildren()
  print tds[1].text, tds[2].text
```

Output:

```
5:16 AM 9:28 PM
5:15 AM 9:30 PM
5:13 AM 9:31 PM
5:12 AM 9:33 PM
5:11 AM 9:34 PM
5:10 AM 9:35 PM
5:09 AM 9:37 PM
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) to make the HTTP requests, and then you'll have web content.

You can get it like this:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com')
html = response.read()
```

[Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is a python HTML parser that is supposed to be good for screen scraping.

In particular, [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Parsing%20a%20Document) is their tutorial on parsing an HTML document.

Good luck!

Comment: It might be an idea to set a maximum on the bytes read. response.read(100000000) or something so those URLs for ISO's don't fill your RAM up. Happy mining.

Answer (score 4):

I use a combination of [Scrapemark](http://arshaw.com/scrapemark/) (finding urls - py2) and [httlib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/) (downloading images - py2+3). The scrapemark.py has 500 lines of code, but uses regular expressions, so it may be not so fast, did not test.

Example for scraping your website:

```
import sys
from pprint import pprint
from scrapemark import scrape

pprint(scrape("""
    <table class="spad">
        <tbody>
            {*
                <tr>
                    <td>{{[].day}}</td>
                    <td>{{[].sunrise}}</td>
                    <td>{{[].sunset}}</td>
                    {# ... #}
                </tr>
            *}
        </tbody>
    </table>
""", url=sys.argv[1] ))
```

Usage:

```
python2 sunscraper.py http://www.example.com/
```

Result:

```
[{'day': u'1. Dez 2012', 'sunrise': u'08:18', 'sunset': u'16:10'},
 {'day': u'2. Dez 2012', 'sunrise': u'08:19', 'sunset': u'16:10'},
 {'day': u'3. Dez 2012', 'sunrise': u'08:21', 'sunset': u'16:09'},
 {'day': u'4. Dez 2012', 'sunrise': u'08:22', 'sunset': u'16:09'},
 {'day': u'5. Dez 2012', 'sunrise': u'08:23', 'sunset': u'16:08'},
 {'day': u'6. Dez 2012', 'sunrise': u'08:25', 'sunset': u'16:08'},
 {'day': u'7. Dez 2012', 'sunrise': u'08:26', 'sunset': u'16:07'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Make your life easier by using `CSS Selectors`**

I know I have come late to party but I have a nice suggestion for you.

Using `BeautifulSoup` is already been suggested I would rather prefer using `CSS Selectors` to scrape data inside HTML

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

main_url = "http://www.example.com"

main_page_html  = tryAgain(main_url)
main_page_soup = BeautifulSoup(main_page_html)

# Scrape all TDs from TRs inside Table
for tr in main_page_soup.select("table.class_of_table"):
   for td in tr.select("td#id"):
       print(td.text)
       # For acnhors inside TD
       print(td.select("a")[0].text)
       # Value of Href attribute
       print(td.select("a")[0]["href"])

# This is method that scrape URL and if it doesnt get scraped, waits for 20 seconds and then tries again. (I use it because my internet connection sometimes get disconnects)
def tryAgain(passed_url):
    try:
        page  = requests.get(passed_url,headers = random.choice(header), timeout = timeout_time).text
        return page
    except Exception:
        while 1:
            print("Trying again the URL:")
            print(passed_url)
            try:
                page  = requests.get(passed_url,headers = random.choice(header), timeout = timeout_time).text
                print("-------------------------------------")
                print("---- URL was successfully scraped ---")
                print("-------------------------------------")
                return page
            except Exception:
                time.sleep(20)
                continue
```

Answer (score 1):

If we think of getting name of items from any specific category then we can do that by specifying the class name of that category using css selector:

```
import requests ; from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.flipkart.com/').text, "lxml")
for link in soup.select('div._2kSfQ4'):
    print(link.text)
```

This is the partial search results:

```
Puma, USPA, Adidas & moreUp to 70% OffMen's Shoes
Shirts, T-Shirts...Under ₹599For Men
Nike, UCB, Adidas & moreUnder ₹999Men's Sandals, Slippers
Philips & moreStarting ₹99LED Bulbs & Emergency Lights
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple web crawler, i used BeautifulSoup and we will search for all the links(anchors) who's class name is _3NFO0d. I used Flipkar.com, it is an online retailing store.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def crawl_flipkart():
    url = 'https://www.flipkart.com/'
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "lxml")
    for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': '_3NFO0d'}):
        href = link.get('href')
        print(href)

crawl_flipkart()
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has good options to scrape the web. The best one with a framework is [scrapy](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/). It can be a little tricky for beginners, so here is a little help. 
1. Install python above 3.5 (lower ones till 2.7 will work). 
2. Create a environment in conda ( I did this). 
3. Install scrapy at a location and run in from there. 
4. `Scrapy shell` will give you an interactive interface to test you code. 
5. `Scrapy startproject projectname` will create a framework.
6. `Scrapy genspider spidername` will create a spider. You can create as many spiders as you want. While doing this make sure you are inside the project directory.

The easier one is to use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and [beautiful soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Before starting give one hour of time to go through the documentation, it will solve most of your doubts. BS4 offer wide range of parsers that you can opt for. Use `user-agent` and `sleep` to make scraping easier. BS4 returns a bs.tag so use `variable[0]`. If there is js running, you wont be able to scrape using requests and bs4 directly. You  could get the api link then parse the JSON to get the information you need or try `selenium`.

Comment: Whether or not you use Anaconda is completely irrelevant here. Creating a virtual environment is basically always a good idea, but you don't need `conda` for that.