# How can I programmatically interact with a website that uses an AJAX JBoss RichTree component?

Tags: python, ajax, jboss, richfaces, screen-scraping

I'm writing a python script to do some screen scraping of a public website. This is going fine, until I want to interact with an AJAX-implemented tree control. Evidently, there is a large amount of javascript controlling the AJAX requests. It seems that the tree control is a JBoss RichFaces RichTree component.

How should I interact with this component programatically?

- Are there any tricks I should know about?
- Should I try an implement a subset of the RichFaces AJAX?
- Or would I be better served wrapping some code around an existing web-browser? If so, is there a python library that can help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) Is probably the most interesting project letting you do javascript stuff in a headless environment with a decent API. While it doesn't support python natively anymore, there are options for interacting with it. Check out the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287490/is-there-a-way-to-use-phantomjs-in-python) for more info.

There is also vanilla webkit (wrapped by Qt and then PyQT). Check out an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2215099/214206).

Hope that helps :)

Comment: This is the kind of library I was looking for, thank you! It looks simple enough to use so I might throw out my python code and rewrite it in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the AJAX calls from your client to the server and interpret the data. Interpreting the AJAX data is easier and less error-prone than scraping HTML any way.

Although it can be a bit tricky to figure out the AJAX API if it isn't documented. A network sniffer tool like wireshark can be helpful there, there may also be useful plugins for your browser to do the same nowadays. I haven't needed to do that for years. :-)

Comment: I was hoping to by-pass the tricky figuring out of the AJAX API as it appears to have lots of long hex-strings in it :)

Comment: @fmark: Well, that doesn't necessarily make it hard to figure out. :-)