# Extracting data from HTML with Python

Tags: python, html

I have following text processed by my code in Python:

```
<td>
<a href="http://www.linktosomewhere.net" title="title here">some link</a>
<br />
some data 1<br />
some data 2<br />
some data 3</td>
```

Could you advice me how to extract data from within `<td>`?
My idea is to put it in a CSV file with the following format: `some link, some data 1, some data 2, some data 3`.

I expect that without regular expression it might be hard but truly I still struggle against regular expressions.

I used my code more or less in following manner:

```
tabulka = subpage.find("table")

for row in tabulka.findAll('tr'):
    col = row.findAll('td')
print col[0]
```

and ideally would be to get each td contend in some array. Html above is a result from python.

Comment: You can use Beautifoulsoup http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html to extract the information rather then using regular expression.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse non-trivial HTML.

Comment: I can use BeautifulSoup to extract data from td but what to do next to work on data inside?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Get [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and just use it. It's great.

```
$> easy_install pip
$> pip install BeautifulSoup
$> python
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as BS
>>> import urllib2
>>> html = urllib2.urlopen(your_site_here)
>>> soup = BS(html)
>>> elem = soup.findAll('a', {'title': 'title here'})
>>> elem[0].text
```

Comment: findAll() returns a list or None, and lists and None don't have a .text() method, so your last line is always an error.

Comment: as 7stud stated above it is a problem indeed

Comment: As of today, the modules are replaced with below modules
https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/
https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html

Ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792650/import-error-no-module-name-urllib2

Answer (score 9):

You shouldn't use regexes on html. You should use BeautifulSoup or lxml.  Here are some examples using BeautifulSoup:

Your td tags actually look like this:

```
<td>newline
<a>some link</a>newline
<br />newline
some data 1<br />newline
some data 2<br />newline
some data 3</td>
```

So td.text looks like this:

```
<newline>some link<newline><newline>some data 1<newline>some data 2<newline>some data 3
```

You can see that each string is separated by at least one newline, so that enables you to separate out each string.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re

html = """<td>
<a href="http://www.linktosomewhere.net" title="title here">some link</a>
<br />
some data 1<br />
some data 2<br />
some data 3</td>"""

soup = bs(html)
tds = soup.find_all('td')
csv_data = []

for td in tds:
    inner_text = td.text
    strings = inner_text.split("\n")

    csv_data.extend([string for string in strings if string])

print(",".join(csv_data))

--output:--
some link,some data 1,some data 2,some data 3
```

Or more concisely:

```
for td in tds:
    print(re.sub("\n+", ",", td.text.lstrip() ) ) 

--output:--
some link,some data 1,some data 2,some data 3
```

But that solution is brittle because it won't work if your html looks like this:

```
<td>
<a href="http://www.linktosomewhere.net" title="title here">some link</a>
<br />some data 1<br />some data 2<br />some data 3</td>
```

Now td.text looks like this:

```
<newline>some link<newline>some data 1some data2some data3
```

And there isn't a way to figure out where some of the strings begin and end.  But that just means you can't use td.text--there are still other ways to identify each string:

1)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re

html = """<td>
<a href="http://www.linktosomewhere.net" title="title here">some link</a>
<br />some data 1<br />some data 2<br />some data 3</td>"""

soup = bs(html)
tds = soup.find_all('td')
csv_data = []

for td in tds:
    a_tags = td.find_all('a')

    for a_tag in a_tags:
        csv_data.append(a_tag.text)
        br_tags = a_tag.findNextSiblings('br')

        for br in br_tags:
            csv_data.append(br.next.strip())  #get the element after the <br> tag

csv_str = ",".join(csv_data)
print(csv_str)

--output:--
some link,some data 1,some data 2,some data 3
```

2)

```
for td in tds:
    a_tag = td.find('a')
    if a_tag: csv_data.append(a_tag.text)

    for string in a_tag.findNextSiblings(text=True):  #find only text nodes
        string = string.strip()
        if string: csv_data.append(string)

csv_str = ",".join(csv_data)
print(csv_str)

--output:--
some link,some data 1,some data 2,some data 3
```

3)

```
for td in tds:
    a_tag = td.find('a')
    if a_tag: csv_data.append(a_tag.text)

    text_strings = a_tag.findNextSiblings( text=re.compile('\S+') )  #find only non-whitespace text nodes
    csv_data.extend(text_strings)

csv_str = ",".join(csv_data)
print(csv_str)

--output:--
some link,some data 1,some data 2,some data 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never used *BeautifulSoup*, but I would bet that it is 'html-tag-aware' and can handle 'filler' space. But since html markup files are structured (and usually generated by a web design program), you can also try a direct approach using Python's `.split()` method. Incidentally, I recently used this approach to parse out a real world url/html to do something very similar to what the OP wanted.

Although the OP wanted to pull only one field from the `<a>` tag, below we pull the 'usual two' fields.

CODE:

```
#--------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*
# Desc: Extracting data from HTML using split()
# Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126686/extracting-data-from-html-with-python
#--------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*

import sys

page     = """blah blah blah
<td>
<a href="http://www.link1tosomewhere.net" title="title1 here">some link1</a>
<br />
some data1 1<br />
some data1 2<br />
some data1 3</td>
mlah mlah mlah
<td>
<a href="http://www.link2tosomewhere.net" title="title2 here">some link2</a>
<br />
some data2 1<br />
some data2 2<br />
some data2 3</td>
flah flah flah
"""

#--------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------#
while 1:#                          M A I N L I N E                             #
#--------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------#
    page = page.replace('\n','')   # remove \n from test html page
    csv = ''
    li = page.split('<td><a ')
    for i in range(0, len(li)):
        if li[i][0:6] == 'href="':
            s = li[i].split('</td>')[0]
#                                  # li2 ready for csv            
            li2 = s.split('<br />')
#                                  # create csv file
            for j in range(0, len(li2)):
#                                  # get two fields from li2[0]               
                if j == 0:
                    li3 = li2[0].split('"')
                    csv = csv + li3[1] + ','
                    li4 = li3[4].split('<')
                    csv = csv + li4[0][1:] + ','
#                                  # no comma on last field - \n instead
                elif j == len(li2) - 1:
                    csv = csv + li2[j] + '\n'
#                                  # just write out middle stuff                    
                else:
                    csv = csv + li2[j] + ','
    print(csv)                    
    sys.exit()
```

OUTPUT:

```
>>> 
= RESTART: C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\board.py =
http://www.link1tosomewhere.net,some link1,some data1 1,some data1 2,some data1 3
http://www.link2tosomewhere.net,some link2,some data2 1,some data2 2,some data2 3

>>>
```