# How to extract required information from a text? python

Tags: python

i want to extrect : tamar tamar,0529589055

from this text and i ahve to do that multiple times.

```
                    <h3 class="name">tamar tamar</h3>
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li>gender:female</li>
                        <li>age:20</li>
                    <li class="phone" data="0529589055">phone:  0529589055</li>
                    <li class="email" data="tamar0529589055@gmail.com">email: tamar89055@gmail.com</li>         <!--                        <a
```

Comment: This question is clearly improvable. Please post a clearer and more detailed question so you also get a good and detailed answer

Comment: This looks like HTML and not just plain old text. [`HTML parser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html#module-html.parser) would be the way to go. There is a very enlightening [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454) on the topic around here. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting data from HTML with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126686/extracting-data-from-html-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

did you think about trying to use regex?
for example a simple `(\w+ \w+)</h3>` will extract the name. at least for the example above.
for the number something like:
`(0\d+)</li>` from the top of my head.

an online regex site that i find easy to use: https://pythex.org

and python regex docs:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

[BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is what you are looking for

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
a='''<h3 class="name">tamar tamar</h3>
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li>gender:female</li>
    <li>age:20</li>
<li class="phone" data="0529589055">phone:  0529589055</li>
<li class="email" data="tamar0529589055@gmail.com">email: tamar89055@gmail.com</li> 
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(a)
print(soup.find('h3',{"class": "name"}).text)
print(soup.find('li',{"class":'phone'}).text)
```