# ImportError: No module named 'urllib2' Python 3

Tags: python, urllib2, python-3.5

The below code is working fine on Python 2 but on Python 3 I get the error:

> "ImportError: No module named 'urllib2'"

```
import urllib2    
peticion = 'I'm XML'
url_test = 'I'm URL'
req = urllib2.Request(url=url_test,
                      data=peticion,
                      headers={'Content-Type': 'application/xml'})
respuesta = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print(respuesta)
print(respuesta.read())
respuesta.open()
```

Please suggest me the reason of error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

check [StackOverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792650/python3-error-import-error-no-module-name-urllib)

```
import urllib.request
url = "http://www.google.com/"
request = urllib.request.Request(url)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
print (response.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 3):

The urllib and urllib2 modules are merged together in python3 as urllib. If you want to make your code compatible with both 2.x and 3.x, I would advise you to look into the [six module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six)