# Heroku Error: No module named 'urllib2'

Tags: python, heroku, urllib2

I need some help. I'm new to Heroku and I'm getting log errors telling me...

```
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib2'
```

I thought `urllib2` package was part of Python?

Any ideas on how to fix this? My app uses `urllib2` extensively.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34740288/importerror-no-module-named-urllib2-python-3 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792650/python3-error-import-error-no-module-name-urllib2

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So the answer was Quite simple. urllib2 is not part of Python 2. I am using Python 2. Python 3 has urllib2.

If fixed my issue of using urllib2 by getting heroku to build the application against python 2 not 3 like it defaults to. The documentation on the Heroku website shows me how to make a "runtime.txt" file to specify the version of Python I would like the app built against.