# ImportError : cannot import name urlopen

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, urlopen

I am trying to open up an URL for my project and here is my code:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
page = urlopen("https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html")
contents = page.read()
```

It's just a simple code for a demo however, when I run the codes, I got the following error **"ImportError : cannot import name urlopen"**

I tried to type "pip install urllib2" into CMD and got the following error as well "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement urllib2...no matching distribution found for urllib2"

How do I solve this error as I'm using python 2.7.12 instead of python3

Comment: It works for me. Can you run import urllib2; print urllib2.__version__

Comment: Actually, another question too - are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: urllib2 is in the python standard library, so you shouldn't have to pip install it.

Comment: Is there another way to solve the error? :/

Comment: I'm thinking about it. You could upgrade to python 3 :P

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you're running 2.7.12? Can you run your code with `import sys; print(sys.version)` and verify the output?

Comment: I got "2.7.12 <v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556....>[MSC v1.500 64 bit...]

Answer (score 58):

I'm going to take an educated guess and assume you are using python3. In python3, urllib2 has been split into [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) and [`urllib.error`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.error.html). [See note at the top of the urllib2 page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#module-urllib2). The function you are looking for is contained in `urllib.request`. Try the following:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
page = urlopen("https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html")
contents = page.read()
```

Answer (score 8):

The answer to this question breaks down into two sections.  The solution differs based on if you are using python 2 or python 3.

In python 3 urllib2 is no longer used.  Try using urllib.request.

In python 2 you may just have a bad install or old version of urllib2.  Try pip install urllib2.

Comment: Further research is that this was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792650/python3-error-import-error-no-module-name-urllib