# How can I download and upload an image using a url in django-python 2.7 using urllib 2

Tags: django, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I am using beautiful soup to scrap data from [Foodily-food website](http://www.foodily.com/r/7fb9b13d0c-peach-lambic-float-with-whiskey-ice-cream-by-a-cozy-kitchen#). I am new to python so I have litle knowledge of file handling in python, my requirement is to scrap data from above above url and then download an image and uploading that to my project.

I have got src of image using:

```
image = soup.find("img",{"itemprop":"image"})['src']
```

Now I need to download this image and then upload it.
I have used below code to retrieve image and read it:

```
 img = urllib2.urlopen(image)
    html = img.read()
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

I have got output in some encoded form and don't what to do further with it.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Downloading a picture via urllib and python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042757/downloading-a-picture-via-urllib-and-python)

Comment: @wiesson that question is asked using urllib and I need to use urllib2

Comment: urllib is also a python standard library. You wrote, you would like to download the image and then "upload it". Where would you like to upload it?

Comment: I just want to save it to some directory I think I just need to download it.

Comment: @wiesson can you tell me if I get image then how I can save it to my directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save an image with urllib2

```
import urllib2
img_src = 'https://unsplash.it/500/300'

response = urllib2.urlopen(img_src)
image = response.read()

with open('your_image_name.jpg', 'wb') as out:
    out.write(image)
```

Please note that urllib2 is different in [python2 and python3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2792652/2050629). 
Regarding django, please take a look at https://github.com/divio/django-filer and/or https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails to save images properly.

Further, to download the images, take a look at http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/ as jinkspadlock suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I use requests and shutil:

```
import requests
import shutil

response = requests.get(iconurl, stream=True)
with open(iconfilepath, 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)
del response
```