# Can't "import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error"

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, urllib

I trying to convert my project to python3.

My server script is server.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*-coding:utf8-*-

import http.server
import os, sys
server = http.server.HTTPServer
handler = http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
server_address = ("", 8080)
#handler.cgi_directories = [""]
httpd = server(server_address, handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

But when I try:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
```

I get this in terminal of python3 ./server.py:

```
    import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
ImportError: No module named request
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Sep/2016 22:47:18] CGI script exit status 0x100
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you sure you're trying to run that code in Python 3 and not Python 2?

Comment: Just to check - what does `python3 -V` show?

Comment: I'm sorry. I have made a mistake. I run 'python3 ./server.py', but I tested on editor that use python2.

Comment: However ploblem still going on python3 server:
    import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
ImportError: No module named request
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Sep/2016 22:47:18] CGI script exit status 0x100

Comment: So complicate! I run python3 ./server.py. But when I using python3 syntax in cgi script 'print(sys.version)', I got '2.7.12 (default, Jul 1 2016, 15:12:24) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]' ?!?!?

Comment: We're missing the context of how cgi is involved here... Apart from an indication it's involved in the error message.. Are you creating a cgi script that's being served via Apache or similar - that may have an older embedded Python (or otherwise be picking up an older Python)?

Comment: I have added code in server.py to above question. thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python3 error: "Import error: No module name urllib2"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792650/python3-error-import-error-no-module-name-urllib2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shebang suggests that code should be run by `python` binary, which is historically associated with Python 2.x releases.

Simply change first line to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```