# Parsing a variable from command line to a url

Tags: python, parsing, download, urllib, argparse

I have a python script called `dlimage`. I want to type a variable in terminal like this `$ python dlimage.py 1 2` and have `1 and 2` correspond to the the url in download_web_image to become `http://www.example.com/1/2.jpg` and download the image. How do I go about doing this?

```
import urllib.request
import argparse

def download_web_image(url):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("num1", "num2")
args = parser.parse_args()

download_web_image("http://www.example.com/"num1"/"num2".jpg")
```

EDIT 2:
I finally got it to work. Thanks everyone for your help!
Code that worked:

```
import urllib
import argparse

def download_web_image(url):
    IMAGE = url.rsplit('/',1)[1]
    urllib.urlretrieve(url, IMAGE)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("num1")
parser.add_argument("num2")
args = parser.parse_args()

download_web_image("https://www.example.com/{num1}/{num2}.jpg".format(num1=args.num1, num2=args.num2))
```

Comment: Did you ever say "argh" trying to remember the details of optparse or argparse API?

Comment: @e4c5 I'm sorry, I don't follow

Comment: You are supposed to tell us what is wrong?  Errors? wrong results?  `still not working` is not enough; I should down vote you for it!

Comment: @hpaulj sorry. i've edited my post.

Comment: So you aren't even getting to the `argparse` stuff.   Try `import urllib`.  The module is `urllib`.  `request` is function in that module.

Comment: Oops, `import urllib.request` works in Py3, in Py2, just use `import urllib`.

Comment: @hpaulj I'm using py3 and I am still getting that error above.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39559384/901925 may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I try part of your code, I get an error:

```
In [1663]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [1664]: parser.add_argument("num1", "num2")
....
ValueError: invalid option string 'num1': must start with a character '-'
```

The arguments to the `add_argument` method are wrong.

What you should be using is:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("num1")
parser.add_argument("num2")
```

In which case the `help` will look like:

```
In [1668]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] num1 num2

positional arguments:
  num1
  num2

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

and testing an input equivalent to `myprog 1 2`

```
In [1669]: args = parser.parse_args(['1','2'])
In [1670]: args
Out[1670]: Namespace(num1='1', num2='2')
In [1671]: args.num1
Out[1671]: '1'
In [1672]: args.num2
Out[1672]: '2'
```

Now I can format a URL with:

```
In [1675]: "https://www.example.com/{}/{}.jpg".format(args.num1, args.num2)
Out[1675]: 'https://www.example.com/1/2.jpg'
```

So there are 2 problems with your code:

Each argument, `num1` and `num2` has to be defined in a separate `add_argument` statement.  Read the docs to see what else you can add to that statement, such as the `help`.  You are trying to define 2 arguments in one statement, and getting an error.

Secondly you need to use a correct format.  I added the `{}` (`{0}` and `{num1}` styles also work).  OR in the older Py2 style:

```
"https://www.example.com/%s/%s.jpg"%(args.num1, args.num2)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. Do you know why I'm still getting the error posted above? I'm using Py3 and the urllib.request is in the standard python 3 library, so I'm not sure where I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
parser.add_argument("num1, "num2")
```

to

```
parser.add_argument("num1", "num2")
```

Comment: both give errors.  When defining a `positional` argument, you give only one string, the `dest`.

Answer (score 1):

for this I would use format:

```
download_web_image("http://www.example.com/{num1}/{num2}.jpg".format(num1=args.num1, num2 = args.num2))
```

Here is an example:

```
num1 = 5
num2 = 6
"http://www.example.com/{num1}/{num2}.jpg".format(num1 = num1, num2 = num2)

output:
'http://www.example.com/5/6.jpg'
```

format makes it easy to insert defined parameters into a string.

Comment: hello, I tried it and it is still not working. I've posted my edited code above.

Comment: The the format function is attached to the string not outside like this: `"http://www.example.com/{num1}/{num2}.jpg".format(num1 = num1, num2 = num2)`. It needs to be `download_web_image("http://www.example.com/{num1}/{num2}.jpg".format(num1=args.num1, num2 = args.num2))`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using python3, I tried to make something simple and as close to the approach you were trying originally. Hope this helps.

```
import urllib.request
import sys
def download_web_image(url):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url)

download_web_image("http://www.example.com/{0}/{1}.jpg".format(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you want to pass N arguments so to generate an URL I would do this :

```
import sys
args = sys.argv[1:]
baseURL = "http://www.example.com"
url = baseURL + "/" + "/".join(args)
print url
```

INPUT:

```
$ python dlimage.py 1 2 3.jpg
```

OUTPUT:

```
http://www.example.com/1/2/3.jpg
```

As for the download, you could try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22682/2948519), or read data at the url and write it as a file named as the last argument :

```
import urllib2
urlResponse = urllib2.urlopen(url)
urlData = urlResponse.read()

outFile = open(args[-1], 'w')
outFile.write(urlData)
outFile.close()
```

I'm behind a work proxy and I get an error when I download the file, might update my answer later this day at home.