# SyntaxError: invalid syntax : except urllib2.HTTPError, e:

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, request, urllib2

Im trying to scrape this xml page for links by keywords but urllib2 is throwing me errors that I can't fix on python3...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import smtplib
import urllib2
from lxml import etree
url = 'https://store.fabspy.com/sitemap_products_1.xml?from=5619742598&to=9172987078'
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
proxies = {'https': '209.212.253.44'}
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=hdr, proxies=proxies)
try:
    page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
    print(e.fp.read())
content = page.read()
def parse(self, response):
    try:
        print(response.status)
        print('???????????????????????????????????')
        if response.status == 200:
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
            self.driver.get(response.url)
            print(response.url)
            print('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')

            # DO STUFF
    except httplib.BadStatusLine:
        pass
while True:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(a.context, 'lxml')
    links = soup.find_all('loc')
    for link in links:
        if 'notonesite' and 'winter' in link.text:
            print(link.text)
            jake = link.text
```

I am simply trying to send a urllib request through the proxy to see if the link is on the sitemap...

Comment: Since you are on Python 3, you should be getting "No module named urllib2" instead (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792650/python3-error-import-error-no-module-name-urllib2).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`urllib2` is not available in Python3. You should be using [`urllib.error`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.error.html) and [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request):

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
...
req = (url, headers=hdr) # doesn't take a proxies argument though...
...
try:
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
...
```

...and so on. Notice however that `urllib.request.Request()` does not take a `proxies` argument. For proxy handling please refer to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.ProxyHandler).

Comment: Hm... It seems python 2.7 is much easier to use for my goals... What is the equivalent in that version?

Comment: It seems like you are already using the Python 2.7 equivalent. Try running your existing code with Python 2 and see what if any your new error messages are.

Comment: You need this: req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=hdr)

Comment: To avoid syntax error in python3.8, update 'page' variable like this: 

page = urllib.request.urlopen(site, headers=hdr)