# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib2'

Tags: python-3.x, komodoedit

So I have `import urllib2` in Python 3.2, using komodo edit (not sure if that matters)

Using it in these spots

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
```

...

```
request = urllib2.Request(src, headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0'})
    srclen = float(urllib2.urlopen(request).info().get('Content-Length'))
```

...

```
request = urllib2.Request(url, headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0'})
    srclen = float(urllib2.urlopen(request).info().get('Content-Length'))
```

...

```
request = urllib2.Request(url, headers=url_headers)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

...

```
request = urllib2.Request(RPTURL + rpt + '.xxx', headers={
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0'})
            srclen = float(urllib2.urlopen(request).info().get('Content-Length'))
        except urllib2.HTTPError:
```

I get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib2'
How can I correct this?

Comment: CHeck [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792650/import-error-no-module-name-urllib2). urllib2 is deprecated in python 3.x. use urllib instaed.