# why in python3 the module 'sklearn.dataset' always raise errors?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
def test():
    iris = load_iris()
```

the code is above,my python version is python 3.6,sklearn version is 0.19.1。the error messages is below:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "E:/pycharm/PyCharm
>   2017.2.3/workspace/machine-learning/DecisionTree.py", line 10, in 
>       from sklearn.datasets import load_wine   File "C:\Users\10649\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\sklearn\datasets__init__.py",
>   line 25, in 
>       from .mldata import fetch_mldata, mldata_filename   File "C:\Users\10649\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\mldata.py",
>   line 12, in 
>       from urllib2 import HTTPError   File "E:\python36\lib\site-packages\urllib2.py", line 220
>       raise AttributeError, attr
>                           ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

is this show that `sklearn.datasets` can't use in `python3`? help me, please

Comment: `raise AttributeError, attr` is a Python 2 syntax. It can't be executed by a Python 3 interpreter.

Comment: The error is in `urllib2` module. Maybe [this can help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792650/import-error-no-module-name-urllib2)

Comment: I'm not sure how but you somehow managed to install a Python 2 package (`urllib2`) to your Python 3.6 `site-packages` directory

Answer (score 1):

Check the conformity between your libraries and your Python interpreter, you seem to be using a python2 package with python3.6

Pick either python version that suits your needs and bundle the appropriate scikit-learn package

You should be able to install the correct packages with these types of commands:

`pip3 install --upgrade pip`

`pip install --user scikit-learn`

You could also go down the path of using [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/) if you are keen of that kind of tool.

I personnaly like [Pipenv](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/) very much.