# Python - Get HTML Source Code of a Web Page

Tags: python, urllib2

I want to get the HTML source from a site ('example.com' for example).

I tried the following:

```
import urllib2

response = urllib2.urlopen("https://example.com")
page_source = response.read()
```

It says:

> 'No module named urllib2'

How can I prevent this error?

Comment: Get started here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792650/import-error-no-module-name-urllib2

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use urllib2 here? Because i would suggest: `from requests import request` with a usage like `resp = request('GET', <url>)`.`pageSource = resp.text`. Also what version of python are you using?

Comment: Btw: this might be relevant to your problem from somebody who wanted to use urllib2 in python3: [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792650/import-error-no-module-name-urllib2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import error: No module name urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792650/import-error-no-module-name-urllib2)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

why you don't use requests module ? :

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://example.com")
print r.text
```

or for answer correctly to you'r question , you can download the urllib2 module using pip and easy_install :

```
pip install urllib2
easy_isntall urllib2
```

for requests:

```
pip install requests
easy_install requests
```

for requests , you should install urllib3:

```
pip install urllib3
easy_install urllib3
```

Comment: Requests works but can't install urllib2 , recieving errors