# `No module named 'urllib2' - how do i use it in Python so I can make a Request

Tags: python-3.x, import, urllib2

Python newbie and just not sure what to do for python

I want to use `urllib2` - `Request` to make a call
How can I do that, for example in the repl.
I can't figure out the right way

```
$ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLerror, HTTPerror
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib2'
>>> from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLerror, HTTPerror
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib2'
>>> import Request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Request'
>>> import urllib2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib2'
>>> 

...
req = Request(URL, json_message) #(URL and json_message defined but not shown here)

...
```

Do I have to install urllib2 into the system separately or something.
Like I said just a Python newbie not knowing steps and syntax. thanks!

The example I am working from has

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError, HTTPError
```

and then uses `Request(...` but when I try that in a python3 repl I get

```
$ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from urllib2 import Request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib2'
>>>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no urllib2 in python3; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792650/import-error-no-module-name-urllib2) for more details. (The short version of the backstory here is that Python2 and Python3 are entirely different types of flying altogether; not all stdlib libraries in Py2 are available in Py3.)

Instead, try `urllib` (similar API);

```
from urllib import request
```

You can hit the urllib documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html), which may help.