# Scrapy installation error, 'ModuleNotFoundError'

Tags: python, scrapy, screen-scraping

I am trying to install Scrapy on Windows by Anaconda, finally some progress was made with help from "https://github.com/dangra/scrapy/archive/moderm-setuppy.zip#egg=Scrapy" but now the error thrown is

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib2'
```

Comment: Hello, @gladi8er welcome to SO, plz take the tour to How to Ask section.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Answer (score 1):

You are likely running some legacy Python 2 code that does not work in Python 3 anymore, because module `urllib2` was changed.

More information in this StackOverflow answer:

[Import error: No module name urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792650/import-error-no-module-name-urllib2)

Your options include

1) Find some other solutions that does not rely on unsupported Python 2

2) Try to get Python 2 installed on your computer and run the code through it

3) Update the code to support Python 3

Comment: Can  you recommend any other way to install scrapy as the offiicial documentation is not working for me

Comment: Here is the offical Scrapy installation guide. Please make sure you have Python 3.5 or higher installed https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html It works. If it does not work then something is wrong with your environment and you are not using Python 3.5 or higher.