# Why does this Python import statement throw an error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have the following imports for mainly external modules:

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from .FrequencySummarizer import FrequencySummarizer
```

The last line is an attempt to import the `FrequencySummarizer` class from the `FrequencySummarizer.py` file in the same folder as the script the imports appear in. When I try and run my script, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

What is wrong with my `import` statement?

Comment: Question appears to have a suitable answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792650/import-error-no-module-name-urllib2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import error: No module name urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792650/import-error-no-module-name-urllib2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the dot(`.`) from your last import, you don't need it there.
Instead use

```
from FrequencySummarizer import FrequencySummarizer
```

Now it'll work fine.