# How to solve NameError: name "urllib2" is not defined in Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

Recently I ran an updated version of the `joy_detection_demo` and I added a few lines which would stream data to ThingSpeak. However, I used the `urllib2` library as:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
```

yet it says in error:

```
f = urllib2.urlopen(groundURL + PRIVATE_KEY +"&field1=%s" % (joy_score))

NameError: name 'urllib2' is not defined
```

I am using Python 3.7 on Raspberry Pi, if you need more lines please tell me.

Comment: You have already imported `urlopen` why are you using `urllib2.urlopen`? just use `urlopen`

Comment: Does this solve your problem? [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792650/import-error-no-module-name-urllib2)

Comment: The solution was to use urlopen as I imported urllib2 as urlopen.