# Is there any modification to execute curl command in python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x, curl, urllib, urllib2, python-2.x

I have a runnable code in python 2.x version for following shell command :

```
curl -XPOST localhost:5055/parse -d '{"q":"tell me about more info on covid", "projects": "ChatBot"}'
```

script for python 2.x is as below :

```
import shutil
import sys
import urllib2
import subprocess
import json
import subprocess, sys
import os, time
import string
import os.path
import os, glob
from datetime import datetime

inputArg="tell me about more info on covid"
data = '{"q":"' + inputArg + '", "projects":"ChatBot"}'
url = 'http://localhost:5055/parse'
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

But when same script is executed in Python 3.x version:

it gives error as follows :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import urllib2
ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'urllib2'
```

- Please let me know what changes shall be done in code so that it will execute in Python 3.x version.
  What are the pre-requisites needed in python 3.x version ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import error: No module name urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792650/import-error-no-module-name-urllib2)

Comment: Just searching ```No module named 'urllib2'``` would've been enough

Comment: I have tried, but in this case I have trained rasa-nlu model in backend and trying to extract data in json format. I had changed code this way `import urllib.request

inputArg="tell me about more info on covid"
data = '{"q":"' + inputArg + '", "projects":"ChatBot"}'
url = "http://localhost:5055/parse"

request = urllib.request.Request(url)

response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)

data_content = response.read()

print(data_content)
`

Comment: got following error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 11, in <module>
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 524, in open
    req = meth(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1255, in do_request_
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this issue without using urllib.request:

```
$ cat test6.py
import requests
import json
inputArg="tell me about more info on covid"
data = {"q":inputArg , "projects":"ChatBot"}
params = json.dumps(data)
url = 'http://localhost:5055/parse'
r = requests.post(url, data=params)
print(r.text)
print(r.status_code, r.reason)
```