# TypeError: descriptor 'split' requires a 'str' object but received a 'bytes'

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, scrape

I am trying to scrape data from ESPN Cricinfo using a python script available on Github. The code is the following.

```
import urllib.request as ur
import csv
import sys
import time
import os
import unicodedata
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

BASE_URL = 'http://www.espncricinfo.com'
for i in range(0, 6019):
url = 'http://search.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/match/search.html?search=first%20class;all=1;page='
    soupy = BeautifulSoup(ur.urlopen(url + str(i)).read())

    time.sleep(1)
    for new_host in soupy.findAll('a', {'class' : 'srchPlyrNmTxt'}):
        try:
            new_host = new_host['href']
        except:
            continue
        odiurl = BASE_URL + urlparse(new_host).geturl()
        new_host = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', new_host).encode('ascii','ignore')
        print (new_host)
        print (str.split(new_host, "/"))[4]
        html = urllib2.urlopen(odiurl).read()
        if html:
            with open('espncricinfo-fc/{0!s}'.format(str.split(new_host, "/")[4]), "wb") as f:
                f.write(html)
```

And the error is in this line.

```
print (str.split(new_host, "/"))[4]
```

TypeError: descriptor 'split' requires a 'str' object but received a 'bytes'
Anyhelp from you would be apperciated. Thanks

Comment: `urllib2` doesn't exist in the py3 stdlib, are you sure this is py3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
str.split(new_host.decode("utf-8"), "/")[4]
```

`.decode("utf-8")` obviously being the most important part. That turns your `byte` object to a string.

On another note, be aware that `urllib2` (which you're using but not importing, by the way) is no longer used (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792650/import-error-no-module-name-urllib2)). Instead, you could use `from urllib.request import urlopen`.

**EDIT**: This is the full code that won't give you **the error you described** in your question. I am highlighting that because without the file previously created, the `with open(...)` statement will give you a `FileNotFoundError`.

```
import urllib.request as ur
import csv
import sys
import time
import os
import unicodedata
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

BASE_URL = 'http://www.espncricinfo.com'
for i in range(0, 6019):
    url = 'http://search.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/match/search.html?search=first%20class;all=1;page='
    soupy = BeautifulSoup(ur.urlopen(url + str(i)).read())

    time.sleep(1)
    for new_host in soupy.findAll('a', {'class' : 'srchPlyrNmTxt'}):
        try:
            new_host = new_host['href']
        except:
            continue
        odiurl = BASE_URL + urlparse(new_host).geturl()
        new_host = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', new_host).encode('ascii','ignore')
        print(new_host)
        print(str.split(new_host.decode("utf-8"), "/")[4])
        html = urlopen(odiurl).read()
        if html:
            with open('espncricinfo-fc/{0!s}'.format(str.split(new_host.decode("utf-8"), "/")[4]), "wb") as f:
                f.write(html)
```

Comment: I tried with the suggested modification, and the error still remains in this line.
Now it says invalid syntax. @Camilo Martinez

Comment: I changed the `print` statement to this, fixed the wrong bracket, and executed it without a problem. You need to change that also in `with open(...)`.

Comment: Can you please write the complete line of code that I need to modify. Thanks in advance

Comment: I edited my answer with the full code. Note the disclaimer.