# speed test library problem and not working correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.10, speed-test

hello I'm writing a Python project to check my speed test and find best servers
here is my code:

```
import speedtest

wifi  = speedtest.Speedtest()

download_speed = wifi.download()
print(f"Your download speed is {download_speed}")

upload_speed = wifi.upload()
print(f"Your upload speed is {upload_speed}")
```

its not working correctly and I'm taking this error massage:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\speedtest.py", line 81, in 
from urllib2 import (urlopen, Request, HTTPError, URLError,
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib2'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Asus\Desktop\main.python\speed-test.py", line 1, in 
import speedtest
File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\speedtest.py", line 86, in 
from urllib.request import (urlopen, Request, HTTPError, URLError,
File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 88, in 
import http.client
PS C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\main.python>  c:; cd 'c:\Users\Asus\Desktop\main.python'; & 'C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'c:\Users\Asus.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.10.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '51940' '--' 'c:\Users\Asus\Desktop\main.python\speed-test.py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\speedtest.py", line 81, in 
from urllib2 import (urlopen, Request, HTTPError, URLError,
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib2'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Asus\Desktop\main.python\speed-test.py", line 1, in 
import speedtest
File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\speedtest.py", line 86, in 
from urllib.request import (urlopen, Request, HTTPError, URLError,
File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 88, in 
import http.client
File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 71, in 
import email.parser
File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\email\parser.py", line 12, in 
from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 27, in 
from email._policybase import compat32
File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\email_policybase.py", line 9, in 
from email.utils import _has_surrogates
File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\email\utils.py", line 28, in 
import random
File "c:\Users\Asus\Desktop\main.python\random.py", line 1, in 
from random import randint

Also I installed the speed test library

Comment: See also: [Import error: No module name urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792650/import-error-no-module-name-urllib2)