# Getting the 'real' Google results with Python

Tags: python, search-engine

I'm trying to do something very simple, get the top result URL of a Google search, f.e. for the search `LMFAO Yes at Pandora` (`at` is intentional here) I want to receive the link `www.pandora.com/music/song/lmfao/yes`. All 3 of the major search engines  return this result without any troubles.

The standard response on stackoverflow seems to be to use the `Google AJAX API` but ... to be blunt, it's total crap. [It returns](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=LMFAO+Yes+at+Pandora) completely weird results i.e.

> `http://lyrics.wikia.com/LMFAO:Yes`
>   `http://www.pandora.com/music/artist/lmfao`
>   `http://www.pandora.com/music/song/goo%2Bgoo%2Bdolls/black%2Bballoon`
>   `http://new.music.yahoo.com/lmfao/`

Unfortunately no amount of tinkering with the query has brought me any success and it gets even worse for more obscure searches, like `Andrea Bauer at ilike`

Bing and Yahoo also provide API's but they require one to get a Dev ID, i.e. no program distribution..

I've also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898574/google-search-using-python-script/3899210#3899210) suggestion that parses the standard Google page but it doesn't seem to work anymore.

The source code of the Google return page in my web browser looks un-searcheable to me..

Is there anything I can do to get the 'real' Google results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xgoogle has unfortunately stopped working for me, but I've found out that Bing doesn't mind scraping their results as long as you use their RSS feed found [here](http://www.bing.com/search?q=meow).

So now I'm just regexing the results page obtained through urlopen.

Answer (score 4):

This library might be of interest to you: [`http://www.catonmat.net/blog/python-library-for-google-search/`](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/python-library-for-google-search/)

```
>>> from xgoogle.search import GoogleSearch, SearchError
>>> try:
...   gs = GoogleSearch("LMFAO Yes at Pandora")
...   gs.results_per_page = 50
...   results = gs.get_results()
...   for res in results:
...     print res.title.encode("utf8")
...     print res.desc.encode("utf8")
...     print res.url.encode("utf8")
...     print
... except SearchError, e:
...   print "Search failed: %s" % e
... 
Yes - LMFAO - Pandora Internet Radio
Information about Yes - LMFAO at Pandora.com. Pandora is the Internet radio service that helps you find new music based on your old and current favorites.
http://www.pandora.com/music/song/lmfao/yes

LMFAO - Pandora Internet Radio
Listen and find out more about LMFAO at Pandora.com. Pandora is the Internet ...
http://www.pandora.com/music/artist/lmfao

search engine - Getting the 'real' Google results with Python ...
I'm trying to do something very simple, get the top result URL of a Google search, f.e. for the search LMFAO Yes at Pandora ( at is intentional here) I want ...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361735/getting-the-real-google-results-with-python

LMFAO:Yes Lyrics - LyricWiki - Music lyrics from songs and albums
This song is performed by LMFAO and appears on the album Party Rock (2009).LMFAO:Yes ... Pandora: search for… LMFAO • Yes. Wikipedia: search for… ...
http://lyrics.wikia.com/LMFAO:Yes

YouTube - LMFAO - YES
Oct 6, 2007 ... JUST ANOTHER DAY IN THE CAR 4 LMFAO... OFFICIAL LMFAO Myspace  - http://lmfaomusic.com http://partyrocklife.com/ for OFFICIAL Party Rock gear ...
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXPT8sw_FjU

Yes Lyrics - Lmfao
The group LMFAO goes double platnium hayyy. I got a party man that's how I live. So I take my elevator to the club in my crib like [Chorus:] Yes it's on and ...
http://www.6lyrics.com/yes10-lyrics-lmfao.aspx

LMFAO - YES LYRICS
1 post - Last post: Jun 3, 2010Lmfao Yes lyrics in the Party Rock Album. These Yes lyrics are performed by Lmfao Get the music video and song lyrics here.
http://www.metrolyrics.com/yes-lyrics-lmfao.html

Easy ChickHEN CFW installer (Without Pandora)
2 posts - 1 author - Last post: Jul 9, 2009Nice post! Smile I have the... Motherboard: TA-079v1, Model: Phat 100x, Hackable: yes, and Creates Pandora: yes. LMFAO! lol! Razz Very Happy ...
http://pspcoding.darkbb.com/t379-easy-chickhen-cfw-installer-without-pandora

Links on "Party Rock" | Facebook
EXCLUSIVE: Jamie Foxx Interview at LMFAO's "YES" Video Shoot - BVTV "Band of the ... Pandora Hau fuck yes party people! lmfao madness ...
http://www.facebook.com/posted.php?id=139241478710&share_id=145095215520613&comments=1

Pandora stays hot with investors - YEA!!! LMFAO!!! - ba.broadcast ...
Aug 31, 2010 ... Subject: Re: Pandora stays hot with investors - YEA!!! LMFAO! ... said that yes, Pandora was running an ad about every half hour. ...
http://groups.google.com/group/ba.broadcast/browse_thread/thread/947fb52042cd8211/41f25665629133cc?show_docid=41f25665629133cc

>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I already did that on Groovy and Java, the point here is asking for google through a URL, then construct a DOM document representing the HTML (Java: [TagSoup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_soup#Tools_to_fix_tag_soup), Python: ??? equivalent). After that, use XPath to gather links from your DOM document so you can "rank" from the Google result page the site you want to rank.

Welcome to black hat [SEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization)?

Comment: @peter No i was just surprised that someone would put in the effort to make cosmetic changes to a (rather useless) post in a - pretty much - dead thread.