# How can I show a gui window with python on Mac

Tags: python, macos, window

I want to know how I can show a simple gui window and open a link to google.com with python on MacOS.

Does somebody know how to do this ?

Thank you for answers

Comment: What's a simple window?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.  
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.
There are many tutorials on line to cover this, as well as previous questions on Stack Overflow that contain similar code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google search using python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898574/google-search-using-python-script)

Comment: @AbhisekRoy goo.gl/images/ytjyLH

Comment: No not a duplicate, I want a window too

Comment: What do you want to see in this window?

Comment: I've found a solution: http://usingpython.com/using-tkinter/

Answer (score 1):

You may use this snippet

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new('https://google.com')
```

Comment: Thank you, this was what I needed for the google.com part of this question