# How to insert a string into a browser text field using python

Tags: python

[Google Search Box Text Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMPTL.png)

What is the fastest way to place a string into a text field using Python. Assuming the string can be parsed from an excel file

```js
import webbrowser  
url = 'http://google.com'  
chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller keyboard = Controller()

import xlrd


workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("Book1.xlsx") sheet =
workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

print (sheet.cell(0,0).value)
```

Comment: Do you need the physical interaction with the UI of Chrome or do you just need to handle the response from a google search? `webbrowser` appears to be for redirecting users to a website in their browser where as if you don't need this, you may be better off with something like `robobrowser`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`webbrowser` module does not offer you much control over your browser. The most direct and common way to approach your immediate problem is you use [`selenium` library](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://google.com")

search_input_box = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
search_input_box.send_keys("test search")
```

Make sure to follow the `selenium` installation steps and have [`chromedriver`](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) installed to be able to control Chrome browser through `selenium`.

Note that this is the direct answer to your question. You do not actually need to automate a regular browser to make a google search request:

- [Google search using python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898574/google-search-using-python-script)