# See if there are any internet results on keyword search

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using python, I would like to search a key word ("apple" for example) and return a true value if google returns any results for this.

I am not searching for a URL, so i cant use anything like:

```
requests.get(URL)
```

Is there a python package that could do this for me, or a similar post on here which I have not noticed?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google search using python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898574/google-search-using-python-script)

Comment: There are APIs like [this one](https://github.com/anthonyhseb/googlesearch) that can return Google search results

Comment: Thank you @CoryKramer, that had solved my issue.