# Easiest way to scrape webpages to save to .csv

Tags: web-scraping

There is a page I want to scrape, you can pass it variables in the URL and it generates specific content.  All the content is in a giant HTML table.

I am looking for a way to write a script that can go through 180 of these different pages, extract specific information from certain columns in the table, do some math, and then write them to a .csv file.  That way I can do further analysis myself on the data.

What is the easiest way to scrape webpages, parse HTML and then store the data to a .csv file?

I have done stuff similar in python and PHP, the parsing of HTML is not the most easiest thing to do, or cleanest.  Are there other routes that are easier?

Comment: Web scraping is **not data-mining**. It's at most "information extraction". or, well, web scraping. Please don't overtag everything as "data mining" that doesn't include databases and analysis...

Comment: This is a pretty idiosyncratic question, because your personal skill with different languages is going to make a big difference here - if you're a Python expert, than Python-based tools are going to be easier. You could make the question more useful to yourself and others by specifying the language you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some experience with python, I would recommend something like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), or in PHP you can use [PhPQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/).

Once you know how to use the HTML-parser, then you can create a "pipes-and-filter" program to do the math and dump it to a csv file.

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081586/web-scraping-with-python) for more info on a Python solution.