# can httplib (python) interact with a page and its javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, web, httplib

I want to write a python script that will ask for reddit post url, go to the page, login with a specified account and upvote the post and the logout.

A) can this be done with python?

B) How would I do this? If you can provide code that would be great, but don't kill yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to interact with JavaScript?

You can reverse engineer Reddit code by looking at AJAX requests made using Firebug or any other debugger, checking cookies, request parameters, etc.

After this you can simulate this requests using Python's urllib by setting same request type (GET vs POST), request parameters and cookies.

Also check this post [web-scraping-with-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081586/web-scraping-with-python)

Answer (score 1):

Besides @Maksym's great suggestion above, you could also use a browser testing tool like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) (which has python bindings) to write a script to interact with the Reddit page directly.  The downside is that it would open a copy of your browser every time it runs, and I'm not sure if that would be an issue for you.

Comment: If you go this route, I *HIGHLY* suggest splinter: http://splinter.cobrateam.info/

Comment: Thanks to Mike for mentioning splinter. I've used Selenium, windmill (http://www.getwindmill.com/) and this one also looks promising.

Comment: Besides that, you can inject custom JavaScript into web page using greasemonkey - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/  Selenium is primary a JavaScript testing tool and has more overhead compared to GreaseMonkey