# How to strip entire HTML, CSS and JS code or tags from HTML page in python

Tags: python, regex, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [BeautifulSoup Grab Visible Webpage Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936466/beautifulsoup-grab-visible-webpage-text)
>   [Web scraping with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081586/web-scraping-with-python)

Say I am a very complex HTML page consisting usual HTML tags, CSS & JS in the middle. We might see all worst cases.

All I want is strip all the above tags/ code and return "text".

In simple terms:

```
<html><body>Text</body></html>
```

This might contain JS, CSS etc. etc..

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup but its not removing JS from the code.. Now ,I am thinking to use Regex.. but not sure how to do

**edit1**

Here is my try on a simple bootstrap html page...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

bs( requests.get(MY-URL).text ).get_text()
```

$ return text

```
html
Home
Le styles
body {
        padding-top: 10%;
        padding-left: 30%;
      }
HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements
[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://htm...html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]
Home | Under Construction
Sample Page 1
The app
might
face some ........
Firefox
. Ple..
/container
var _gaq = _gaq || [];

  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = do...............
  })();
```

Comment: BeautifulSoup should allow you to remove the content of the `<script>` tag (i.e. the JavaScript), doesn't it?

Comment: Hh no. you don't need regex for that, show us your code and the html, and where you got stuck.

Comment: take a look at my above question. Actually, I am working on a very big database of urls..all are random. I need to extract "Text" of "body". How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django using this function to strip tags from text:

```
def strip_tags(value):
    """Returns the given HTML with all tags stripped."""
    return re.sub(r'<[^>]*?>', '', force_unicode(value))
```

(You won't need the force_unicode part)