# Beautifulsoup get rid of embedded js and css in html

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parser

I need to parse multiple html through `requests.get()`. I just need to keep the content of the page and get rid of the embedded javascript and css. I saw the following post but no solution works for me.
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344476/how-to-strip-entire-html-css-and-js-code-or-tags-from-html-page-in-python`, `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936466/beautifulsoup-grab-visible-webpage-text`, and `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081586/web-scraping-with-python`

I got a working code that doesn't strip js either css... here is my code...

```
count = 1
for link in clean_urls[:2]:
    page = requests.get(link, timeout=5)
    try:
        page = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser').text
        webpage_out = open(my_params['q'] + '_' + str(count) + '.txt', 'w')
        webpage_out.write(clean_page)
        count += 1
    except:
        pass


webpage_out.close()
```

I tried to include solutions from the links above mention but no code works for me. 
What line of code can get rid of the embedded js and embedded css

## Question Update 4 OCT 2016

The file that `read.csv` is something like this...

```
trump,clinton
data science, operating system
windows,linux
diabetes,cancer
```

I hit gigablast.com with those terms to search one row at the time. One search will be `trump clinton`. The result is a list of urls. I `requests.get(url)` and I process those urls getting rid of `timeouts`, `status_code = 400s`, and building a clean list of `clean_urls = []`. After that I fire the following code...

```
count = 1
for link in clean_urls[:2]:
    page = requests.get(link, timeout=5)
    try:
        page = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser').text
        webpage_out = open(my_params['q'] + '_' + str(count) + '.txt', 'w')
        webpage_out.write(clean_page)
        count += 1
    except:
        pass


webpage_out.close()
```

On this line of code `page = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser').text` I have the text of the entire web page, including styles and scripts if they were embedded. I can't target them with BeautifulSoup because the tags are no longer there. I did try `page = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')` and `find_all('<script>')` and try to get rid of the script but I ended up erasing the entire file. The desired outcome will be all the text of the html without any...

```
body {
    font: something;
}
```

or any javascript...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $some code
)};
```

The final file should have no code what so ever, just the content of the document.

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible sample with input and a desired output? Thanks.

Comment: I'm going to update the question.

Answer (score 1):

I used this code to get rid of javascript and CSS code while **scraping** HTML page

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://corporate.walmart.com/our-story/our-business'
r = requests.get(url)
html_doc = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
title =  soup.title.string

for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.decompose()    

with open('output_file.txt', "a") as text_file:
    text_file.write("\nURL : "+ url)
    text_file.write("\nTitle : " + title)
    
               
    for p_tag_data in soup.find_all('p'):
        text_file.write("\n"+p_tag_data.text)
        
    for li_tag_data in soup.find_all('li'):
        text_file.write("\n"+li_tag_data.text)
        
    for div_tag_data in soup.find_all('div'):
        text_file.write("\n"+div_tag_data.text)
```