# Get data from html table

Tags: javascript, python, sql, html-table

I need to get data from several pages. Data are storied in html tables.
I want to generate SQL file which saves them to my database.
One of my aims are [these results](http://www.diamondleague-birmingham.com/Live-StartlistsResults/Overview/200m/).

The easiest way to process sites could be JavaScript, but how to run script on each site and write results into my hard drive?

I could also download all needed sites using wget and processed them with Python, if it had necessary libraries to work with html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood you basically have to scrape some content from the web and store it in a database.

I would probably go for a Python script which crawls the webpage by using the `urllib2` library and then parse it in some way depending on the needed content (regexp, BeautifulSoup, etc...).

Take a look at this question: [Web scraping with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081586/web-scraping-with-python)

Comment: seems legit, I will try it :)