# (Python) Trying to isolate some data from a website

Tags: python, urllib

Essentially the script will download images from wallbase.cc's random and toplist pages. Essentially it looks for a 7 digit string which identifies each image as that image. It the inputs that id into a url and downloads it. The only problem I seem to have is isolating the 7 digit string.

What I want to be able to do is..

Search for `<div id="thumbxxxxxxx"` and then assign `xxxxxxx` to a variable.

Here's what I have so far.

```
import urllib
import os
import sys
import re


#Written in Python 2.7 with LightTable


def get_id():
    import urllib.request
    req = urllib.request.Request('http://wallbase.cc/'+initial_prompt)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    the_page = response.read()
    for "data-id="" in the_page


def toplist():
    #We need to define how to find the images to download
    #The idea is to go to http://wallbase.cc/x and to take all of strings containing <a href="http://wallbase.cc/wallpaper/xxxxxxx" </a>
    #And to request the image file from that URL.
    #Then the file will be put in a user defined directory

    image_id = raw_input("Enter the seven digit identifier for the image to be downloaded to "+ directory+ "...\n>>> ")

    f = open(directory+image_id+ '.jpg','wb')
    f.write(urllib.urlopen('http://wallpapers.wallbase.cc/rozne/wallpaper-'+image_id+'.jpg').read())
    f.close()


directory = raw_input("Enter the directory in which the images will be downloaded.\n>>> ")

initial_prompt = input("What do you want to download from?\n\t1: Toplist\n\t2: Random\n>>> ")
if initial_prompt == 1:
    urlid = 'toplist'
    toplist()

elif initial_prompt == 2:
    urlid = 'random'
    random()
```

Any/all help is very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use a web scraping library like BeautifulSoup, see eg. [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081586/web-scraping-with-python) on web scraping in Python.

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

# download and parse HTML
url = 'http://wallbase.cc/toplist'
html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# find the links we want
links = soup('a', href=re.compile('^http://wallbase.cc/wallpaper/\d+$'))
for l in links:
    href = l.get('href')
    print href                # u'http://wallbase.cc/wallpaper/1750539'
    print href.split('/')[-1] # u'1750539'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only use the default library, you could use regular expressions.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'<div id="thumb(.{7})"')

...

for data-id in re.findall(pattern, the_page):
    pass # do something with data-id
```

Comment: I couldn't resist linking to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454