# scraping product pages of websites to get price information

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to scrap product page of few websites like amazon,ebay to get the price of the product.I learnt its easier to write scrappers in python.I wanted to know whether there are any python libraries frameworks that makes it easier to scrap.I don't know from where to start .Can anyone guide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) - top google result.

If you prefer a lighter approach try [writing your own scraper](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/).

This question has also already been answered: [Web scraping with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081586/web-scraping-with-python)