# Browsing/parsing html pages in python

Tags: python, html, parsing, browser, web-scraping

I'm trying to put together a little collection of plugins that I need in order to interact with html pages. What I need ranges from simple browsing and interacting with buttons or links of a web page (as is "write some text in this textbox and press this button") to parsing a html page and sending custom get/post messages to the server.
I am using Python 3 and up to now I have **Requests** for simple webpage loading, custom get and post messages,
**BeautifulSoup** for parsing the HTML tree and I'm thinking of trying out **Mechanize** for simple web page interactions.

Are there any other libraries out there that are similar to the 3 I am using so far? Is there some sort of gathering place where all Python libraries hang out? Because I sometimes find if difficult to find what I am looking for.

Comment: Useful python libraries: https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsefulModules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of tools/libraries for web-scraping really depends on the multiple factors: purpose, complexity of the page(s) you want to crawl, speed, limitations etc.

Here's a list of tools that are popular in a web-scraping world in Python nowadays:

- [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/)
- [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)
- [splinter](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/)
- [ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/)
- [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) (and [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests))
- [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)

There are also `HTML` parsers out there, these are the most popular:

- [BeautifuSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)
- [lxml](http://lxml.de)

`Scrapy` is probably the best thing that happened to be created for web-scraping in Python. It's really a web-scraping framework that makes it easy and straightforward, `Scrapy` provides everything you can imagine for a web-crawling.

Note: if there is a lot AJAX and js stuff involved in loading, forming the page you would need a real browser to deal with it. This is where [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) helps - it utilizes a real browser allowing you to interact with it by the help of a `WebDriver`.

Also see:

- [Web scraping with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081586/web-scraping-with-python)
- [Headless Selenium Testing with Python and PhantomJS](http://www.realpython.com/blog/python/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs/#.U0_ppeZdXLY)
- [HTML Scraping](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/)
- [Python web scraping resource](http://jakeaustwick.me/python-web-scraping-resource/)
- [Parsing HTML using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709079/parsing-html-python)

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Serban nope, forgot mechanize :)