# Python: How to access a webpage, click specific links and copy the data within them to a text file?

Tags: javascript, python, html, bioinformatics, biopython

I am quite new to python and programming, and all I know how to do is write simple scripts for my routine office work. However, I have run into a scenario where I have to use python to access a particular webpage, which is a search output of a particular bioinformatics web server.

In that webpage, there is a table, in which the second column is a hyperlink that opens up a little pop up box with a FASTA file of the protein sequence.

I would like to be able to write a script that clicks these links systematically, one after the other, copy the FASTA sequence of each of the links, and paste them into a text file.

Is this kind of automation possible with python? If so, where do I start, in terms of modules to access internet explorer/webpages etc.? If you could kindly guide me in the right direction or give me an example script, I could try and do it myself!

Thank you so much!

I would post what I have tried, but I have literally no idea where to start!

Comment: Look into http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ and http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: Try reading the urllib doc here : https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html

Comment: Could you give the name/URL of the specific bioinformatics web server you are trying to access?

Comment: Your problem falls in the category we call webscraping. See this location for a bunch of python tools that can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081586/web-scraping-with-python

Comment: Thank you all so much for your responses. @BioGeek, the web server is a proprietary server from Thomson reuters. You can make a trial account for 30 days if you want to give it a whirl. Its called SequenceBase. https://usgene.sequencebase.com

Answer (score 3):

This takes about a minute and a half to run for me, after which it opens a text file with the sequences. You need of course to add your credentials, etc. at the end.

```
import os
import mechanize
import cookielib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urlparse import urljoin

class SequenceDownloader(object):

    def __init__(self, base_url, analyzes_page, email, password, result_path):
        self.base_url = base_url
        self.login_page = urljoin(self.base_url, 'login')
        self.analyzes_page = urljoin(self.base_url, analyzes_page)
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.result_path = result_path
        self.browser = mechanize.Browser()
        self.browser.set_handle_robots(False)

        # set cookie
        cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
        self.browser.set_cookiejar(cj)

    def login(self):
        self.browser.open(self.login_page)
        # select the first (and only) form and log in
        self.browser.select_form(nr=0)
        self.browser.form['email'] = self.email 
        self.browser.form['password'] = self.password 
        self.browser.submit()

    def get_html(self, url):
        self.browser.open(url)
        return self.browser.response().read()

    def scrape_overview_page(self, html):
        sequences = []
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
        table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'styled data-table'})
        table_body = table.find('tbody')

        rows = table_body.find_all('tr', {'class': 'search_result'})
        for row in rows:
            cols = row.find_all('td')
            sequence_url = cols[1].a.get('href')
            sequence_html = self.get_html(sequence_url)
            sequence_soup = BeautifulSoup(sequence_html)
            sequence = sequence_soup.find('pre').text
            sequences.append(sequence)
        return sequences

    def save(self, sequences):
        with open(result_path, 'w') as f:
            for sequence in sequences:
                f.write(sequence + '\n')

    def get_sequences(self):
        self.login()
        overview_html = self.get_html(self.analyzes_page)
        sequences = self.scrape_overview_page(overview_html)
        self.save(sequences)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    base_url = r'https://usgene.sequencebase.com'
    analyzes_page = 'user/reports/123/analyzes/9876'
    email = 'user1998510@gmail.com'
    password = 'YourPassword'
    result_path = r'C:path\to\result.fasta'

    sd = SequenceDownloader(base_url, analyzes_page, email, password, result_path)
    sd.get_sequences()
    os.startfile(result_path)
```

Comment: Wow! I am so grateful for people like you, to take the time to go through a stranger's problems, dedicate their time to answer the question and educate beginners like me! Thank you so much for this script. I am studying it closely to see which modules you have used ( I have downloaded mechanize, BeautifulSoup). I am assuming cookielib and urlparse/urljoin  are part of python 2.7 (the version I have), as it didn't flag any errors. I changed the username/id/analyses page etc options at the bottom. I am getting an error still when I run the script though. I post this in the next message.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):  File "Path/Sequence_retrieval_from_SequenceBase_Stackoverflow.py", line 71, in <module>
    sd.get_sequences()
  File "Path/Sequence_retrieval_from_SequenceBase_Stackoverflow.py", line 59, in get_sequences
    sequences = self.scrape_overview_page(overview_html)
  File "Path/Sequence_retrieval_from_SequenceBase_Stackoverflow.py", line 37, in scrape_overview_page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Comment: Ah, its to do with BeautifulSoup 3 / Beautiful Soup 4. I got the bs4 now.

Comment: Hey BioGeek, sorry for the delay in responding, but yes! in the end it worked perfectly with Bs4! great script. Ofcourse, the website themselves added the function after I complained that users shouldn't be made to write their own scripts for the money we pay to use that service!

Comment: @Meet Please create a new question with the website URL and what you tried.