# How get a fragment of the code from External HTML (web site) with python

Tags: python, html

I want to get a fragment from a HTML website with python.

For example from the url http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Steven_Universe_Wiki I want to get the text in the box "next Episode", as a string. How can I get it?

Comment: 1. Learn python. 2. Code the code. 3. In case of specific problems, ask here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081586/web-scraping-with-python

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? I suggest using the `requests` module for accessing the HTML, and `BeautifulSoup` for parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all download BeautifulSoup latest version from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4)
and requests from [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

con = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(con)
text = soup.find_all("a",href="/wiki/Gem_Harvest").text;
print(link)
```