# Extract data from BSE website

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests

How can I extract the value of Security ID, Security Code, Group / Index, Wtd.Avg Price, Trade Date, Quantity Traded, % of Deliverable Quantity to Traded Quantity using Python 3 and save it to an XLS file. Below is the link.

https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/smartlink-network-systems-ltd/smartlink/532419/

PS: I am completely new to the python. I know there are few libs which make scrapping easier like BeautifulSoup, selenium, requests, lxml etc. Don't have much idea about them.

Edit 1:
I tried something

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
URL = 'https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/smartlink-network-systems-ltd/smartlink/532419/'
r = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
table = soup.find('div', attrs = {'id':'newheaddivgrey'})
print(table)
```

Its output is `None`. I was expecting all tables in the webpage and filter them further to get required data.

```
import requests
import lxml.html
URL = 'https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/smartlink-network-systems-ltd/smartlink/532419/'
r = requests.get(URL)
root = lxml.html.fromstring(r.content)
title = root.xpath('//*[@id="SecuritywiseDeliveryPosition"]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td')
print(title)
```

Tried another code. Same problem.

Edit 2:
Tried selenium. But I am not getting the table contents.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.3\bin\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/smartlink-network-systems-ltd/smartlink/532419/')
table=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="SecuritywiseDeliveryPosition"]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td')
 print(table)
driver.quit()
```

Output is `[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="befdd4f01e6152942c9cfc7c563a6bf2", element="0.13124528538297953-1")>]`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081586/web-scraping-with-python

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Added code in the original post.

Comment: the `requests` library is best suited to individual HTTP requests. It will not download the whole web page, only the HTML file at the requested location; this means that any other content, such as that loaded by Javascript, will not be downloaded. When opening the URL provided, a loading message appears momentarily, suggesting that the actual data is indeed loaded by JS. Consider looking through the site's JS and reverse-engineering it to directly fetch the data you need, rather than scraping it from a rendered page.

Comment: Can you please help me with the small piece of code that scraps javascript data? Please use the link given in my post.

Comment: The easiest way to handle this page is to use [Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium). Each of the different tables on this page is loaded dynamically through different AJAX requests. So, if you want to use `requests` to scrape this, you'll have to get the data from multiple urls (which will become a bit tedious for someone who is new to scraping). For e.g., the table containing *Security ID*, *Security Code*, etc is loaded from this url - https://www.bseindia.com/SiteCache/1D/CompanyHeader.aspx?Type=EQ&text=532419

Comment: How did you get the below link. https://www.bseindia.com/SiteCache/1D/CompanyHeader.aspx?Type=EQ&text=532419 . I have tried using selenium but not getting the table contents. Included code in the original post.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar. Can you please look in to my code using selenium.

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263824/get-html-source-of-webelement-in-selenium-webdriver-using-python

Comment: I checked the link. It is for the older version of selenium. I am using selenium 3.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After loading the page with Selenium, you can get the Javascript modified page source using `driver.page_source`. You can then pass this page source in the BeautifulSoup object.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/smartlink-network-systems-ltd/smartlink/532419/')
html = driver.page_source
driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('div', id='SecuritywiseDeliveryPosition')
```

This code will give you the *Securitywise Delivery Position* table in the `table` variable. You can then parse this BeautifulSoup object to get the different values you want.

The `soup` object contains the full page source including the elements that were dynamically added. Now, you can parse this to get all the things you mentioned.